# Jackson One-to-many Many-to-One infinite Loop deserialization errors

Tags: jackson, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 models -

Member.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="members")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="member_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="member_name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name="member_joining_date")
    @NotNull
    private Date joiningDate = new Date();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="member_type",columnDefinition="varchar(255) default 'ORDINARY_MEMBER'")
    private MemberType memberType = MemberType.ORDINARY_MEMBER;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tmod",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Meeting> meetingsAsTmod = new ArrayList<Meeting>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tableTopicsMaster",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Meeting> meetingsAsTableTopicsMaster = new ArrayList<Meeting>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="generalEvaluator",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Meeting> meetingsAsGeneralEvaluator = new ArrayList<Meeting>();

    ...getters and setters, constructors...
```

}

Meeting.java

```
public class Meeting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="meeting_id")
    @NotNull
    private int meetingId;

    @Column(name="word")
    @NotNull
    private String word;

    @Column(name="theme")
    @NotNull
    private String theme;


    @Column(name="meeting_date")
    @NotNull
    private Date meetingDate;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="tmod_member_id")
    @NotNull
    private Member tmod;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="table_topics_master_member_id")
    @NotNull
    private Member tableTopicsMaster;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="general_evaluator_member_id")
    @NotNull
    private Member generalEvaluator;

    ...getters,setters,constructors...
```

I wanted my program to return the IDs of the meetings in meetingsAsTmod, meetingsAsTableTopicsMaster etc, instead of the list of meetings, which has the users, which inturn has the list of meetings and creates the loop

How can I show the Ids of the members in the meeting and also Ids of the meetings in which the member played that role? (instead of the full object) using Jackson?

If not, how can I work around this problem?

PS - I tried using @JsonIdentityInfo. But it prints recursively all the objects if it hasnt been printed before. Instead of printing

```
{
"meetingId": 23,
"word": "meet2",
"theme": "meet2",
"meetingDate": 1514387641632,
"tmod": 4,
   ....
   ....
 }
```

It prints -

```
 {
"meetingId": 23,
"word": "meet2",
"theme": "meet2",
"meetingDate": 1514387641632,
"tmod": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Prateek4",
    "joiningDate": 1514375322337,
    "memberType": "ORDINARY_MEMBER",
    "meetingsAsTmod": [
        {
            "meetingId": 20,
            "word": "meet2",
       ....
        .....
```

Comment: A verbose way is to create a DTO object with the fields you want and populate the fields from your actual model.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan yea thats one way. But im trying to use Jackson based solutions as much as possible.. Lets see..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to the many-to-one and one-to-many mappings

```
   @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
                    ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
```

Change id to whatever is the Id in the object